# recaptcha https problem on https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, recaptcha

I am using recpatcha on an SSL site but I am not getting the image on some browsers because the ssl certificate of it has been expired !

https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/

if I reference the non-secure link, the browser will give warning message.

so what is the alternative?

I am using it under ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Remy says, you need to update the links to point at Google's servers. See the [announcement](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha-announce?pli=1) regarding the expiration of the old URL.

If you are using the .NET Library then you can update to the [latest version](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/downloads/list?q=label:aspnetlib-Latest)

If you did not use the library then you can see the modifications made to the library [here](http://code.google.com/p/recaptcha/source/diff?path=/trunk/recaptcha-plugins/dotnet/library/RecaptchaControl.cs&format=side&r=135), and update your URLs in the same manner.

i.e. update `https://api-secure.recaptcha.net` to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api`

Answer (score 1):

ReCaptcha was acquired by Google.  Have you updated your code to use the new Google links yet?

Comment: nope. I haven't seen the document for changes. where should I see the changes that have to be performed?