# reCaptcha and SSL web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, recaptcha

I using a reCaptcha on my web page under asp.net mvc. This web site have a SSL certificated, and I having and problem with reCaptcha.
This is my code on View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/challenge?k=***Public key****"> </script>
<noscript>
<iframe src="https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/noscript?k=***Public key****" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br />
<textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge" />
</noscript>
```

and this code is that I have on AccountController:

```
private bool PerformRecaptcha()
{
    var validator = new RecaptchaValidator
    {
        PrivateKey = "**Private Key***", 
        RemoteIP = Request.UserHostAddress,
        Response = Request.Form["recaptcha_response_field"],
        Challenge = Request.Form["recaptcha_challenge_field"]

    };

    try
    {
        var validationResult = validator.Validate();

        if (validationResult.ErrorMessage == "incorrect-captcha-sol")
            ModelState.AddModelError("ReCaptcha", string.Format("Please retry the ReCaptcha portion again."));

        return validationResult.IsValid;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ReCaptcha", "an error occured with ReCaptcha please consult documentation.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my library version is 1.0.5.0.

When I load the register form I have this alert on Opera:

*The rules server certificate matches the server name. Do you want to accept?*

If I accept this certificate, displays reCaptcha  code, but if not, I don't view reCaptcha Code.

Can you help me with this?
If you need more information about my code, feel free to ask to me.

Regards.

Comment: Is that Google's ASP.NET reCaptcha control? Is this only an issue in Opera?

Comment: No, it happend on all web browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need to change the url you are using to include recaptcha. A number of people had the same problem in April. [Recaptcha let the certificate](http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha/browse_thread/thread/57baacc2a067035a) expire for "api-secure.recaptcha.net". If you change it to use the "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/XXX" url instead of "https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/XXX", it should definitely fix your issue.

It looks like this one has actually been answered before: [recaptcha https problem on https://api-secure.recaptcha.net/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865880/recaptcha-https-problem-on-https-api-secure-recaptcha-net). Since you are using the .NET library, I think your answer is to upgrade your version.

Comment: Actually, he's not using the .NET Library for the View part which needs to be changed.

Comment: I can't test this solution until Monday, but I think that this is going to be the solution. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Sharpening up on JasonStoltz's answer:

- You are already using the latest DLL version, there's no need to update this
- You can/should use RecaptchaControlMvc.GenerateCaptcha() method in your View instead of writing your own (it will use the new URL)

Comment: Adrian, thansk for your answer, on Monday I try both solutions.