# Recaptcha for .NET MVC having more trouble with SSL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, https, recaptcha

I'm attempting to get Recaptcha for .NET working with ASP.NET MVC 4.0 on an https site that is using SSL. I've been reading up on it and the problem seems prolific, but I'm having a hard time finding a solution.

I've seen this related topic here [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865880/recaptcha-https-problem-on-https-api-secure-recaptcha-net) and it did not solve the problem. I am following the documentation here : [RecaptchaNET Documentation](http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20Use%20Recaptcha%20in%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%20Web%20Application&referringTitle=Documentation)

I have made an ad-hoc solution work by running the page in non HTTPS and just copying and pasting the raw HTML code, and changing the various URLS. But I'd like to make this work with the actual HTML helper. Can anyone help? Has this changed since that original topic?

Comment: What's the error you get when calling using HTTPS?

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: I did not. Sorry, I was unable to respond to this until now. This problem stil lexists.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few posts about this out there for the change google made to the api.  Basically, [RecaptchaNET](http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com/) wasn't supporting google's latest api endpoints for this.

If you check your version, this is fixed in version 1.3.

Try downloading the latest version from [CodePlex](http://recaptchanet.codeplex.com/) and using that dll.

or the [nuget here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/RecaptchaNet/).